# How to hide .html extension with web hosting?

Tags: html, web

I have a website hosted with cPanel X on goDaddy and I am trying to hide the .html extension when you click new pages. How can I go about hiding the .html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at link Below:

[How to remove .php, .html, .htm extensions with .htaccess](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

If you want to remove the .html extension from a html file for example yoursite.com/wallpaper.html to yoursite.com/wallpaper you simply have to alter the last line from the code above to match the filename:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Perfect. Really helped. @Jatin

Answer (score 0):

Go to root directory, create a new file called .htaccess(that is the file name i.e .htaccess) and add this code below in that file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```